# An apparent mismatch of tense : « je tenais à vous remercier »

Tags: temps-grammatical

I just said the following sentence, using the present tense « tiens », but my co-worker pointed out later that I should have used the past tense « tenais ».

> Puisque je viens tout juste de rejoindre l’équipe, je **tenais** *{(x) **tiens**}* à me présenter aussi brièvement que possible. Je suis donc le docteur XXX.

What I find interesting is:

The act of introducing myself is about to happen several seconds later; it’s not something already done. So it seems logical to say « je **tiens** à me présenter » in the present, as it is essentially the same as saying « je **vais** me présenter ».

I wonder if the same goes for the following two instances. Does the past tense « je tenais à » fit the bill, despite the act of saying something not having happened yet?

> Tout d'abord je **tenais** *{(x) **tiens**}* à vous remercier infiniment pour votre aide tout au long de mes recherches. Merci pour votre soutien.
>
> Avant de raccrocher, je **tenais** *{(x) **tiens**}* à vous dire quelque chose : ~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je suis entièrement d'accord avec la réponse de @stackreader sur le fait que dans ton premier exemple le passé se justifie dans la mesure où on se réfère à une action passée et on n'est plus dans le désir de faire (ce qu'exprime tenir) mais dans la réalisation de cet désir. Mais l'emploi du présent ne choque pas, les deux sont acceptables.

Par contre dans les deux exemples suivants j'emploierais le présent à cause de la présence des adverbes de temps qui situent la volonté exprimée par tenir dans l'instant où je parle. Donc :

> **Tout d'abord** je **tiens** à vous remercier...
>
> **Avant de** raccrocher, je tiens à vous dire...

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, they are both acceptable.
And if you search on google, you apparently get about 3 times more hits with the present tense.
The usage of "tiens/tenais" is the same as "to want".
It shows your desire to do something, and not the action itself.
It is why present tense and past tense both make sense.
Just as in :

> I want to say thank you to all of you.
>   I wanted to say thank you to all of you.

Arguably, since you are defining the source of your desire to introduce yourself as being from the past(because I just joined), it might feel more natural to say "tenais". Since it might feel like you have had that desire since the time you joined.